# Compilation error about operator reloading using boost::variant

Tags: c++, boost, boost-variant

I'am trying to learn boost.variant. However, the code which I copied from a book won't pass the compilation:

```
class var_print : public boost::static_visitor<void>    
{
public:
    template<typename T>    
    void operator()(T &i) {  
        i *= 2;   
        cout<<i<<endl;  
    }
};
```

Here is how I tried to use it.

```
    typedef boost::variant<int,double,string> var_t;
    var_t v(1); //v->int 
    boost::apply_visitor(var_print(),v);
```

The compiler generates the following error:

ERROR:no match for 'operator*=' in 'i *= 2'

That puzzles me,since template function will determine the type of parameter whenever it's called and int should defined the operator *=.

Comment: Yes, but `v` _isn't_ an integer, it's a `boost::variant`.

Comment: @Joachim That doesn’t matter: `v` is not the function parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have a separate `operator()` for `std::string&` since no operator `*=` is defined for `std::string`.

In addition, your operator must be marked `const` since you are passing a temporar visitor instance to `apply_visitor`.

Comment: I tried to change the variant definition to variant<int,float> but still get the same error.

Comment: Oops...Seems that I made a silly mistake. Thanks for your reply.